# Can't observe computed property

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-cli

I've got a controller sorting posts first, then there's a filter applied to them. Sadly when I use `{{#each post in filteredPosts}}` in my template they don't live update.

**How can I achieve the sorting on multiple columns (in different directions), then the filtering AND still have new and deleted posts appear in the list live?**

import Ember from 'ember';

```
export default Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  sortProperties: ['isPublished:asc', 'createdAt:desc'],
  sortedPosts: Ember.computed.sort('model', 'sortProperties'),
  filterPost: '',

  filteredPosts: function() {
    var filterText = this.get('filterPost').toLowerCase()
    return this.get('sortedPosts').filter(function(post){
      return post.get('title').toLowerCase().indexOf(filterText) > -1
    })
  }.observes('sortedPosts').property('filterPost'),

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your computed property has two things wrong with it.

1. You're using both `.observes()` and `.property()`. You only need `.property()`. `.observes()` is for when you want to make side-effect changes when a property updates.
2. You're only watching `sortedPosts`, which means that your property will only recalculate when the `sortedPosts` iterable itself changes, not when any of the content changes. Because you're filtering by the `title` property, you should be watching that on every instance. You can read more about this [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties-and-aggregate-data/).

Your computed property should look something like this:

```
filteredPosts: function() {
    ...
}.property('sortedPosts.@each.title', 'filterPost')
```